# How can I override my JWT auth dependency in the endponits in FastAPI testing?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I managed to override my DB dependency for my testing in FastAPI but when I try to apply the same technique for overriding my JWT auth dependency I still get a 422 response with the following detail:

```
{'detail': [{'type': 'missing', 'loc': ['query', 'fake_jwt'], 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/missing'}]}
```

I followed all documentation and suggested posts on this topic of overriding dependencies for testing and still haven't found my issue. Does anyone know what's the problem here?
Here are the involved codes:

conftest.py

```
def init_test_db(_app):
    engine = create_engine(
        settings.sql_alchemy_database_url,
        connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
    )

    def override_get_session():
        with Session(engine, autoflush=True) as session:
            with session.begin():
                yield session

    def override_get_session_no_transaction():
        with Session(engine) as session:
            yield session

    _app.dependency_overrides[get_session] = override_get_session
    _app.dependency_overrides[get_session_no_transaction] = (
        override_get_session_no_transaction
    )
    SQLBaseModel.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    with Session(engine) as session:
        for user in fake_users.values():
            session.add(user)
        session.commit()
    return engine

@pytest.fixture
def app_with_db():
    from app.main import app

    test_engine = init_test_db(app)
    yield app
    app.dependency_overrides = {}
    drop_test_db(test_engine)

@pytest.fixture()
def app_with_db_and_jwt(app_with_db):
    def override_jwt_dependency(fake_jwt):
        print(fake_jwt)
        return TokenData(id=1, email="jointhedarkside@empire.com")
    app_with_db.dependency_overrides[validate_access_token] = override_jwt_dependency
    yield app_with_db
```

test.py

```
def test_me_success(app_with_db_and_jwt):
    darth_user = fake_users["darth"]
    client = TestClient(app_with_db_and_jwt)
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer fakejwt.super.fake"}
    me_response = client.get("/users/me", headers=headers)
    print(me_response.json())
    assert me_response.status_code == 200
```

schemas.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class TokenSchema(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str


class TokenData(BaseModel):
    id: int
    email: str
```

router.py

```
@users_router.get("/me", response_model=ResponseUserSchema)
def me(user_data: jwt_dependency, db: get_session_dependency):
    user = db.exec(
        select(User).where(User.email == user_data.email, User.id == user_data.id)
    ).first()
    return user
```

dependencies.py

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="auth/token")

token_dependency = Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
def validate_access_token(token: token_dependency):
    try:
        token_payload = jwt.decode(
            token, key=settings.jwt_secret_key, algorithms=settings.jwt_algorithm
        )
        email = token_payload.get("sub")
        user_id = token_payload.get("id")
        if email is None or user_id is None:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Could not validate user",
            )
        else:
            return TokenData(id=user_id, email=email)
    except JWTError as e:
        logger.logger.exception(e)
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Could not validate user"
        )


jwt_dependency = Annotated[TokenData, Depends(validate_access_token)]
```

Comment: Where do you expect `fake_jwt` to be provided from? No need to have the parameter at all; your overidden dependency does not depend on anything, so you should be able to just leave it empty.

Comment: At first I thought the same. But if i remove this parameter i get the following error: `fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 1 validation errors:
{'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ('response',), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/model_attributes_type'}`

Comment: But does your `select(User).where(User.email == user_data.email, User.id == user_data.id)` return a user that matches the one you're faking? You haven't defined the return value as optional, so FastAPI assumes that there will always be a user that gets returned.

Comment: yes, that query should always return a user instance. I already checked and the db is populated with the correct data on the fixture and still i have the same issue. I made sure of that. It's weird because my dependency override for the DB works just fine